# Searching 3 words in TAGS Redis?

Tags: redis, redisearch

Im using a simple redis query searching on tags but for some reason when you introduce 3 words it doesn't work? is there a way around this? any other combination less than 3 is fine.

```
FT.SEARCH idx:content:details "@deleted:0 @contentAlias:{Games}" - works

FT.SEARCH idx:content:details "@deleted:0 @contentAlias:{Games and Drills}" - doesnt work
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and include your [mcve] - presumably you can demonstrate inserting a few items of representative sample data and then show which ones you hope to retrieve and how you are trying or what is failing.

Comment: Im sorry how is that not a minimal reproduction? im saying searching on tags with three words doesnt work? I cant make it anymore clear cut im afraid.

Comment: A minimal example should allow someone who is offering their time to assist you, at no cost to you, to run your code and get your results/errors. In general, the easier you make it for folks to help you, by for example providing representative data, the more likely they are to do so.

Comment: Im sorry, i dont know what more i can do, you literally have to run that search query on a tag that contains three words, how much more can i provide?

Comment: Although I recognized this problem immediately, adding the call to FT.CREATE would help future folks who run into this issues and try searching for it. Tagging it as RediSearch would be good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TAGS in RediSearch can be impacted by stop words—i.e. really common words in English that aren't useful for searching. Like 'the', 'is', and 'and'—which you have in your query.

You need to escape the spaces in your query with a backslash. However, the backslash itself will also need escaped. Try this:

```
FT.SEARCH idx:content:details "@deleted:0 @contentAlias:{Games\\ and\\ Drills}"
```